# Angular 2 extending RouterModule throws Uncaught Error: Type RouterOutlet is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angularjs, router, ngroute

Why if I extend the RouterModule I got the duplication of RouterOutlet declaration:

```
metadata_resolver.js:505Uncaught Error: Type RouterOutlet is part of the declarations of 2 modules: RouterModule and CustomRouterModule! Please consider moving RouterOutlet to a higher module that imports RouterModule and CustomRouterModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes RouterOutlet then import that NgModule in RouterModule and CustomRouterModule.
    at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22259:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22169:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22160:54)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleSummary (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22073:31)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22147:51
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22143:49)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleSummary (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22073:31)
```

Here is how I extend the RouterModule.

```
import {RouterModule, Routes, ExtraOptions, Router} from "@angular/router";

export class CustomRouterModule extends RouterModule{

    public static forRoot(routes: Routes, config?: ExtraOptions)
    {
        // Do something with routes here ...
        return super.forRoot(routes, config);
    }

    public static forChild(routes: Routes, router?: Router)
    {
        // Do something with routes here ....
        return super.forChild(routes);
    }

}
```

Do I get also ngModule decorator metadata 'extended' ? What I would like to achieve is to do some routes processing when adding the routes to the router. I can not access the routes before I add them to router because I lazy-load modules.